# Finding the most common section from the visible cells in a collection view

Tags: functional-programming, swift

My goal is to determine, of all of the currently visible cells in a collection view, which section has the most visible cells.

Start by getting the index paths for the visible cells:

```
let visible = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems // [IndexPath]
```

Originally I used an `NSCountedSet` followed by mapping and sorting.

```
let counted = NSCountedSet(array: visible.map { $0.section })
let section = counted.allObjects.map { ($0, counted.count(for: $0)) }.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }.first?.0 as? Int
```

This works but I don't like `NSCountedSet` because it deals with `Any`.

I then replaced the use of `NSCountedSet` with `reduce` by reducing the visible array into a dictionary and then using a similar map and sort.

```
let counted = visible.reduce([Int: Int]()) { (result, path) -> [Int: Int] in
    var updated = result
    updated[path.section, default: 0] += 1
    return updated
}
let section = counted.keys.map { ($0, counted[$0]!) }.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }.first?.0
```

This works as well but I'm hoping there are ways to improve this.

Two main questions:

1. Can the `reduce` closure be improved? Is there a better way to return the updated dictionary where the keys are section and the values are the count?
2. Once I have the dictionary of sections and counts, is there a better way to find the section with the highest count? Is there something better than mapping to a tuple, sorting those tuples, and finally grabbing the first one?

BTW - If there is a tie for highest count, I don't care which of those sections is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Re 1:** You can take advantage of [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce) which was introduced in Swift 4 precisely for this purpose:

> This method is preferred over [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) for efficiency when the result is a copy-on-write type, for example an Array or a Dictionary.

See also [SE-0171 Reduce with inout](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0171-reduce-with-inout.md):

> **Motivation**
>
> The current version of reduce needs to make copies of the result type for each element in the sequence. The proposed version can eliminate the need to make copies (when the inout is optimized away).

In your case:

```
 let counted = visible.reduce(into: [Int: Int]()) { (result, path) in
    result[path.section, default: 0] += 1
}
```

The compiler can also infer the type of the initial accumulator automatically if the closure consists only of a single statement:

```
let counted = visible.reduce(into: [:]) { (result, path) in
    result[path.section, default: 0] += 1
}
```

**Re 2:** A dictionary *is* a collection of key/value pairs, therefore it can be sorted directly, without mapping each key to a tuple first:

```
let section = counted.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value }).first?.key
```

Even better, use [`max(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2906531-max) to find the dictionary entry with the maximal value:

```
let section = counted.max(by: { $0.value < $1.value })?.key
```

This is shorter and eliminates the intermediate arrays and the dictionary lookup. It is more efficient than sorting an array because only a single traversal of the collection is done. And even if the forced unwrapping is safe in your case, it is nice not to have it.

---

One could also make this a generic method for sequences

```
extension Sequence {
    func mostFrequent<T: Hashable>(by map: (Element) -> T) -> T? {
        let counted = reduce(into: [:]) { (result, elem) in
            result[map(elem), default: 0] += 1
        }
        return counted.max(by: { $0.value < $1.value })?.key
    }
}
```

which is then used as

```
let section = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.mostFrequent(by: { $0.section })
```

Comment: Excellent. That `reduce(into:)` was just what I needed to make that part cleaner. And I had been thinking about how to use `max` but I forgot about being able to use it like this with a dictionary. Great info. The extension is a great touch too.